# Color scheme for macvim only - how?

Tags: vim, macvim

I want to use solarize for macvim, but I want the default for when I am in vi. I assume I put a dew lines of code in my .vimrc... but what do I put in there?

Answer (score 22):

MacVim uses the ~/.gvimrc, so you could set it up in the ~/.gvimrc file. Or you could use `has("gui_running")`:

```
if has("gui_running")
  colorscheme solarized
endif
```

Both versions should work.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use

```
if has("gui_macvim")
   colorscheme solarized
endif
```

If you want solarized only for MacVim but not other graphical vim clients.